# how to disable wpf Datagrid validation in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

while selecting value from datagridcombocolumn it's showing row validation error as ! mark. i just wanted to turn off that validation from datagrid via c#.

Is that possible to get?

Comment: Check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.rowvalidationrules(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) out.

Comment: Did you implement any validation? You won't be able to set a source property to a value of an incompatible type regardless of whether you turn off the validation.